# React loading screen on function processing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I making an Electron/React word to pdf converter. I want to make loading screen when function converts files.

```
<HashRouter>
  <GlobalStyle />
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <AppStyle>
      <Navigation />

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/documents">
          <AddDocumentForm <---------Add document form component
            setIsLoading={setIsLoading}
            isLoading={isLoading}
          /> 
        </Route>
        <Route path="/documents/:id">
          <Document />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/lists"></Route>
        <Route path="/lists/:id"></Route>
      </Switch>
      {isLoading && <Loading />} <----Loading Component
    </AppStyle>
  </ThemeProvider>
</HashRouter>
```

In AddDocumentForm component on subbmiting form I change state of isLoading to true and when files are converted I changed it back to false. Nothing is happening, I will be very grateful if someone can explain me why.

PS. Sorry for typos.

Comment: Maybe updating the state doesn't re-render the route's component. You can try using Context instead. If you'd create a codesandbox which reproduces the issue, it will be much easier to help

Comment: Thank You very much. I just forgot to not call function directly on callback. So i just added () => setIsLoading(false). Sorry for making a trouble. All thanks to your codesandbox suggestion :D

Answer (score 0):

I just called function directly in callback. Added "() =>" and everything is working.